# Parsing JSON using codable and ignoring first layer of JSON

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable

I have JSON like this:

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "",
"result": {
    "buy": [
        {
            "Quantity": 0.0056,
            "Rate": 18527
        },
        {
            "Quantity": 0.11431426,
            "Rate": 18526
        }
    ], 
    "sell":[
        {
            "Quantity": 8.20604116,
            "Rate": 18540
        },
        {
            "Quantity": 0.95600491,
            "Rate": 18574.99999998
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

and another set of JSON like this:

```
{
      "lastUpdateId": 1027024,
      "bids": [
        [
          "4.00000000",     // PRICE
          "431.00000000",   // QTY
          []                // Can be ignored
        ]
      ],
      "asks": [
        [
          "4.00000200",
          "12.00000000",
          []
        ]
      ]
    }
```

What is the best way to parse these two responses using codable. They both need to be parsed using the same struct or need to be converted to the same struct (whatever will do the job faster). I don't want to create a struct for the entire first response because I am not going to use keys like `"success"` and `"message"`. I basically want to ignore those and get directly to the `"result"` key But in the second response, I will being using all the data so I have created a struct for that called `TotalOrderBook`. What is the best way to do this?

What is confusing me is ignoring the keys `"success"` and `"message"` in the first JSON response and getting straight to the value for the key `"result"`. Is it possible to do that without creating an additional struct?

This is what I have right now. I would like to avoid adding another struct since the only thing I really need is the values under buy/bid and sell/sell.

```
struct TotalOrderBook:Codable{
    var buy:[UniversalOrder]?
    var sell:[UniversalOrder]?

    var bid:[UniversalOrder]?
    var ask:[UniversalOrder]?

    var buyOrderBook: [UniversalOrder] {
        return bid ?? buy ?? [UniversalOrder]()
    }
    var sellOrderBook: [UniversalOrder] {
        return ask ?? sell ?? [UniversalOrder]()
    }

    var updatedTime:Date
}


struct UniversalOrder:Codable{
    var price : Double {
        return Double(rate ?? binPrice ?? 0)
    }

    var size : Double {
        return Double(quantity ?? binQuantity ?? 0 )
    }
    //let numOrders : Int

    var quantity:Double?
    var rate:Double?

    var binPrice:Double?
    var binQuantity:Double?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rate = "Rate"
        case quantity = "Quantity"
        //case numOrders, binPrice,
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        binPrice = Double(try container.decode(String.self)) ?? nil
        binQuantity = Double(try container.decode(String.self))  ?? nil
        quantity = nil
        rate = nil
    }
}
```

This is how I am decoding:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value) //value is the response from Alamofire

var theWholeOrderBook:UniversalOrder!
do {
    theWholeOrderBook = try decoder.decode(UniversalOrder.self, from: data)
} catch let error {
    //print ("error is \(e) ** \(value)")

}
```

Comment: Note that Swift is a type inferred language `return bid ?? buy ?? []` and `catch let error`  is redundant just `catch`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions directly, yes it is very easy to ignore the `success` and `message` key-value pairs and head straight to `results`.

Despite this it will be a bit complicated to have a single struct to parse both of these JSON responses.
Both of them have a very different structure which will make it easier to use two different structs to use encoding. To highlight some differences :

1. `buy`, `sell` are nested inside `results`. `bids`, `asks` aren't.
2. The keys are completely different.
3. `buy`, `sell` have an array of key-value pairs while `bids`, `asks` simple have an array of values.

Codable structs should be simple and clear. It's better to have two of those corresponding to each response.

Comment: perfect. Once I get those two I should them convert them into one? How do I ignore the success and message key-value pairs?

Comment: I would recommend to have different structs to encode them. You don't have to "ignore" any keys. Simply parse the keys that you want to and don't bother about the rest.

Comment: but I don't want to have a struct with just the `result` value. isn't that kind of pointless? There is no way to just get straight to the values within the `result` key

Comment: Your code is already doing that.
My answer is to solve your specific question about having two different structs, if you want a guide to JSON in Swift 4 then here's one... https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/

Comment: I have looked at this guide already. It is amazing. But I still wasn't able to figure out how to ignore that success and message without creating a new struct to parse them. There is no way to do it when you do the decoding? I have added to my answer to show you how I am doing the decoding